# JS Not Running Locally - Works On JSFiddle - JQuery Tubeplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Using the JQuery plugin [Tubeplayer](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin), I'm able to get the currentTime of a YouTube video to display correctly on jsfiddle in chrome and in firefox locally. In chrome locally, start, stop and videoURL works properly while currentTime displays 0 (it should update as the video plays, like it does in the fiddle).
**Question:**
Why does the javascript work on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lny4Q/1/) in chrome, but not locally?
Other posts have suggested wrapping the code in

```
$(function(){
    //code
});
```

but it doesn't seem to affect it, for me.
Here is the code from my index.html - what is running locally:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>tubeplayer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='player'></div>
<button id="play">PLAY</button>
<button id="pause">PAUSE</button>
<button id="time">Current time</button>
<button id="url">Video URL</button>
<div id="display"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.tikku.com/scripts/ui/tubeplayer/jQuery.tubeplayer.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var video_id = '9BkBGdnUNSk';
    $("#player").tubeplayer({
        width: 560, // the width of the player
        height: 315, // the height of the player
        initialVideo: video_id
    });
    $('#pause').click(function(){
        $('#player').tubeplayer("pause");
    });
    $('#play').click(function(){
        $('#player').tubeplayer("play");
    });
    $('#time').click(function(){
        $('#display').text($("#player").tubeplayer("data").currentTime);
    });
    $('#url').click(function(){
        $('#display').text($("#player").tubeplayer("data").videoURL);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: are you running this file directly in your browser or using any server on localhost of browser? If you are running directly without using any local server, try using XAMPP or WAMP server and then try again running these files

Comment: Are there any console errors?!

Comment: I've ran the file directly and I've uploaded it to my remote server, which has the same effect as if it were local.
8 errors show up when I hit play (but the play button functions) and none when I hit current time. The error is:
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Comment: @saylor https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5788

Comment: @Charlie thanks for that, but unfortunately changing http:// to https:// didn't fix it. Although, the buttons do also work in incognito if that's worth anything.